# Discord.py Passing multiple optional parameters with discord.Member as some and a URL as another

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Im trying to figure out how to construct the parameters of this call:

```
async def lfg(self, ctx, level, *users: discord.Member, link):
    //does stuff
```

users could be between 0 and 3 @users. the Link is optional and may or may not be passed in.

The current writing of this function gives me this error:

```
&lfg level1

discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "https://link" not found.
```

When I change it to:

```
async def lfg(self, ctx, level, link="", *users: discord.Member):
```

It works if I provide the link or if I do not have a link or a user, but if I provide a user and no link, it thinks the user I provided is the link.

Is there a way for me to say something like:

```
async def lfg(self, ctx, level, link="": string, *users: discord.Member):
//if the parameter passed in as 'link' is not a string, it just puts it into a user parameter
```

If this isnt possible, any idea how I can get the multiple optional parameters thing Im looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special `commands.Greedy` converter, it will consume arguments until it can't, errors will be silently ignored.

```py
async def lfg(self, ctx, level, users: commands.Greedy[discord.Member], link: str=None):
    print(users, link)
```

Both the `users` and `link` arguments are optional, it's worth mentioning that `users` it's going to be a list (empty if it fails to convert any argument)

#### Reference:

- [`commands.Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Greedy)